# Event Control with KeyPress 'Tab'

Tags: javascript, html

So I have several input forms that are disabled until they are filled out in sequence because of data calls to the server based on their selections. I have a custom dropdown that allows me to do a typeahead and click the item I want. When I click the item, the field unlocks with a combination of onblur and onchange events that take place for my data model. The issue that comes into play for me is I want the user to be able to tab. But when I hit tab, the onblur and onchange haven't disabled the field so it skips several fields that it shouldn't. Is there any suggestions on preventing a tab keypress skipping the disabled element? Can I tab and focus on a disabled element?

Comment: i don't think you can focus on a disabled element like that. but maybe you can work around it by creating a "disabled" css class instead of actually disabling it. it will look disabled to the user, but the tab will still work.

Comment: btw, your question is a little confusing. a code example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, as the docs say:

> A form control is disabled if its disabled attribute is set, or if it is a descendant of a fieldset element whose disabled attribute is set and is not a descendant of that fieldset element's first legend element child, if any.
>
> A form control that is disabled **must prevent any click events** that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.

So you can not click on those elements, and you can not focus element, that can not be clicked.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-disabled

So the only option if you need to allow focusing of those elements is not to use `disabled` attribute at all. You could use `.disabled` class instead and bind on key events to suppress editing of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are willing to temporarily enable the disabled element (thus making it writable), this can be done by checking whether the **[next element](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** has the **[`disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled)** with **[`hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute)**. If it does, you can change this attribute to `false` **before** the `keydown` returns `true`, and thus the `keyup` will tab to the disabled element.

Additionally, you can set a new attribute `wasDisabled`, which you can then check against with `$(this)[0]`. If the element has this class, you can **re-disable** the element once you tab off it again.

This can be seen in the following jQuery example:

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) {
    if ($(this).next()[0].hasAttribute('disabled')) {
      $(this).next().attr('disabled', false);
      $(this).next().attr('wasdisabled', true);
    }
    if ($(this)[0].hasAttribute('wasdisabled')) {
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input>
<input disabled>
<input>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yeah but you can still write to that element, that is probably not what OP is asking for. I misread your answer first, thought you will make it disabled again once you tab to it, but then you will lose the focus, right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you would lose the focus if you disabled it **while** it was currently focused. However, I've expanded the answer to disable it again once tabbing off it, which is probably as close as you can get. The element cannot be clicked on at any disabled point, and it can only be enabled through tabbing from the previous element.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching it to a readonly property. The readonly allowed me to tab to it and focus on it while not being able to type in it until the the blur and change completed.